# Convert lambdas to method references

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

Can somebody help me convert the following code to use method references?  I'm trying to wrap my head around this new syntax but I quickly get lost when it gets more complex than a single variable getting mapped to a single method call:

```
getWorkspaces().stream().forEach((ws) -> {
            DataStoreInfo defaultDataStore = getDefaultDataStore(ws);
            if (defaultDataStore != null) {
                other.setDefaultDataStore(ws, defaultDataStore);
            }
        });
```

I started with this, but it doesn't work :)

```
getWorkspaces().stream()
               .map(this::getDefaultDataStore)
               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
               .map(other::setDefaultDataStore);
```

Edit:  By "it doesn't work", I mean the IDE complains on the last line under "setDefaultDataStore" that it cannot resolve the method.  I wish I could start with something that works, but I don't know how to get there.  I'm very confused on how to use method references to call a method that takes 2 parameters and how that gets mapped.  I've converted some code that looks like this:

```
 getMaps().stream().forEach((m) -> {
            other.add(m);
        });
```

to this:

```
getMaps().forEach(other::add);
```

But I get lost when it gets more complex.  I was hoping there was an obvious solution on how to write same code with method references.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Please be more specific, and ideally provide a [mcve].

Comment: @GhostCat: I haven't, but "it doesn't work" without any more detail makes it a far from ideal question.

Comment: Before trying to "use a method-reference", you need to write something that works without it... Second snippet wouldn't work even with lambda expression and isn't related to the use of method references. First of all, You need two parameters in `setDefaultDataStore`. So you need to store them.

Comment: probably he doesnt know what map does its intermediate operation  , he needs to close his stream with foreach again. check for  what terminal operation and intermediate operation does.

Comment: Your last step should be a `forEach` instead of `map`. And you won't be able to use a method reference for it because you have too many arguments.

Comment: to make it simple, you cannot use a method reference with a method that takes two arguments

Comment: @tfosra Are you sure?  There seem to be examples of calling methods with two arguments, like with the comparators on this page http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: Forget about method-reference, and try to write the same code you want to write but with a lambda expression. As commented before, this is not the issue.

Comment: What is **other** in `other::setDefaultDataStore`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your code to the lambda version like this but its not clean  as expected.

```
words.stream().map(ws -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(ws, getDefaultDataStore(ws)))
              .filter(e -> e.getValue() != null)
              .forEach(e -> setDefaultDataStore(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

Note : e is the short for entry .

Answer (score 5):

You can read a lot of useful information here about method references
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

If your lambda does nothing but calls existed method, you can replace it with method reference. So if you are comfortable with lambdas you will cope with method references easily.

There are 4 kinds of them

1. Reference to a static method - ContainingClass::staticMethodName
2. Reference to an instance method of a particular
   object - containingObject::instanceMethodName
3. Reference to an instance
   method of an arbitrary object of a particular
   type - ContainingType::methodName
4. Reference to a
   constructor - ClassName::new

Returning to your question:
.map(other::setDefaultDataStore);

You shouldn't use map function to perform some side operations over stream members, it is used for transforming stream into another. User foreach instead

```
getWorkspaces().stream()
               .map(this::getDefaultDataStore)
               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
               .foreach(other::setDefaultDataStore);
```